# Trouble reading a .txt file

Tags: c++, text-files, fstream

I have the following as my code:

```
string file_name;
int weight;
int distance;
char slash = '/';
string line = "";

ifstream myfile(file_name);

cout << "Enter the path of the file you want to read from. \n";
cin >> file_name;
ifstream inFile (file_name);
inFile.open(file_name.c_str());
if (inFile.is_open())
{
    while (getline (inFile,line) )
    {
        inFile >> setw(7) >> weight >> setw(7) >> distance;
        cout << "\n" << setw(4) << weight << setw(4) << distance;
    }
    inFile.close();
}
else cout << "Unable to open file";
```

I am trying to move through each line of a file that the user inputs the path of. The file i am using has hundreds of lines of data and I would like to move through each line and separate each element (each line has the same set of elements) then move to the next line and do the same thing. Nothing is being extracted however and nothing is being cout'ed. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this isn't functioning as intended?

Comment: Are there any other errors messages?  Could you paste a sample of your data?

Comment: @roelofs nope no other error messages

Comment: Data sample :                                                                                        2016/3/16 2016/3/23 f 581 3980 3 n n 15 Ken Jones x232@gmail.com

Comment: @roelofs Data sample: 2016/5/28 2016/11/3 s 248 17 3 n y 20 Katy Perry kperr@gmail.com 
2016/2/13 2016/8/8 w 79 1123 2 n y 21 Betty White bwhite@gmail.com 
2016/2/22 2016/4/14 f 641 162 2 n n 22 Earl Grey earlgrey@gmail.com

Comment: Why don't you use `std::strtok`? It might be simpler. One more thing, `getline (inFile,line)` and `infile >>` are contradicting. You need only one of them.

Comment: What do you do with `getline (inFile,line)`?

Comment: @GMichael when i remove either infile or getline(infile,line) the code returns an error

Comment: @GMichael if you were going the C route, `scanf` would be far better than `strtok` for this.

Comment: @lottie3 You should keep `getline()` and parse the `line` using `strtok`

Comment: @user4581301 I do not trust `scanf`: I faced too many problems with it. I prefer to parse manually but be able to debug it and see what actually happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going X-Y on you. This is C++, so lets try some object orientation, shall we?

Instead of working with many different pieces of data and complex parsing rules, I suggest imposing order on the data and using the order to simplify the parsing.

I'm only demonstrating with the dates, but the rest of the information can also be collected into classes and structures as your needs and logic suggests.

```
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

// a simple date structure. Could be a class, but this is C++. structs ARE classes.
struct Date
{
    string  year;
    string  month;
    string  day;

};

// make a input stream reader for Date
istream & operator>>(istream & in, Date & date)
{
    getline(in, date.year,'/'); // grab everything up to the first /
    getline(in, date.month,'/'); // grab from first / to the second /
    getline(in, date.day, ' '); // grab from second / to first space
    return in;
}

// make a output stream writer for Date
ostream & operator<<(ostream & out, const Date & date)
{
    return out << date.year << '/' << date.month << '/' << date.day;
}
int main()
{
    string file_name;
    string line;

    // using a preloaded string stream instead of file. Easier to debug.
    stringstream inFile("2016/3/16 2016/3/23 f 581 3980 3 n n 15 Ken Jones x232@gmail.com\n2016/5/28 2016/11/3 s 248 17 3 n y 20 Katy Perry kperr@gmail.com\n2016/2/13 2016/8/8 w 79 1123 2 n y 21 Betty White bwhite@gmail.com\n2016/2/22 2016/4/14 f 641 162 2 n n 22 Earl Grey earlgrey@gmail.com");
    while (getline(inFile, line)) // read a line
    {
        stringstream linestream(line); // put line into another stream
        Date est; // allocate a couplte Dates
        Date mv;
        linestream >> est >> mv; // read into Dates

        cout << "\n"
             << est.year << '/' << est.month << '/' << est.day << " " // print hard way
             << mv; // print easy way
    }
}
```

Sample output:

```
2016/3/16 2016/3/23
2016/5/28 2016/11/3
2016/2/13 2016/8/8
2016/2/22 2016/4/14
```